# Using a loop through a list of a list to filter another list

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension

Given the following 2 lists:

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 'ABC'], [2, 3, 'ABC']]
list_2 = ['ABC 1.csv', 'ABC 2.csv', 'ABC 3.csv', 'ABC 4.csv', 'ABC 5.csv']
```

What code can be written to give:

Desired output:

```
list_3 = ['ABC 1.csv', 'ABC 2.csv', 'ABC 3.csv']
```

My attempt:

```
count = 0
while count < len(list_1):
    list_3 = [i for i in list_2 if str(list_1[int(count)][0]) in i or str(list_1[int(count)][1]) in i and list_1[int(count)][2] in i]
    count += 1
```

Comment: Why are you getting such odd inputs, can't you get the list_1 in a more usable form?

Comment: Since you accepted none of the answers, could you please tell us what is still missing in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a `wanted` list from `list_1` containing all allowed entries. Then take each entry from `list_2` that you find in the `wanted` list.

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 'ABC'], [2, 3, 'ABC']]
list_2 = ['ABC 1.csv', 'ABC 2.csv', 'ABC 3.csv', 'ABC 4.csv', 'ABC 5.csv']

wanted = []
for n1, n2, prefix in list_1:
    wanted.append(f'{prefix} {n1}.csv')
    wanted.append(f'{prefix} {n2}.csv')

result = [entry for entry in list_2 if entry in wanted]
print(result)
```

You might have duplicates in the `wanted` list but that doesn't matter.

---

An even more flexible one-liner (please notice the numbers in the first entry of `list_1`):

```
list_1 = [[1, 2, 5, 'ABC'], [2, 3, 'ABC']]
list_2 = ['ABC 1.csv', 'ABC 2.csv', 'ABC 3.csv', 'ABC 4.csv', 'ABC 5.csv']
print([entry for entry in list_2 if entry in {f'{prefix} {n}.csv' for *numbers, prefix in list_1 for n in numbers}])
```

This will give you `['ABC 1.csv', 'ABC 2.csv', 'ABC 3.csv', 'ABC 5.csv']`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
list_1=[[1, 2, 'ABC'], [2, 3, 'ABC']]
list_2=['ABC 1.csv', 'ABC 2.csv', 'ABC 3.csv', 'ABC 4.csv', 'ABC 5.csv']

numbers = []
for l in list_1:
    if l[0] not in numbers:
        numbers.append(l[0])
    if l[1] not in numbers:
        numbers.append(l[1])
        
list_3 = []
for l in list_2:
    if int(l[4]) in numbers:
        list_3.append(l)
print(list_3)
```

Comment: This lacks some flexibility. Use `list_1=[[1, 2, 'ABC'], [2, 3, 'CDE']]` or `list_1=[[1, 2, 'AB'], [2, 3, 'AB']]` and this solution suddenly isn't a solution anymore.